# how to pass a variable dynamically in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dynamic

i am trying to pass the string variable dynamically

like this

```
def calling():

    str='Login_CSA' 
    import importlib
    mod = importlib.import_module(str)
    mod.%str(10, 20, 30, 40)

calling()
```

but i am unable to pass the variable getting syntax error "syntax error" and i tried with concatinating

like

```
mod.+str(10,20,30,40)
```

still iam not able to get

can u guys show me how to pass a variable dynamically like other languages in python

Comment: I don't understand what you expect `mod.%str(10, 20, 30, 40)` to do. Can you show what the desired result would be?

Comment: You are inventing new syntax.

Comment: @john john2 iam not inventing new syntax i said i tried like that..like other languages whether it will work or not can u please show me solution how can we pass variables dynamically

Comment: @somesh: Can you answer my question above? It's not clear what you mean by "pass variables dynamically", you need to define it. If you expect `mod.%str(10, 20, 30, 40)` in your code to call a `Login_CSA` function in the `Login_CSA` module, then thefourtheye's answer is what you need. If you want something else instead, you need to explain what.

Comment: @blckknght in my framework i will get string values i,e module names dynamically call from excel sheet one after other so.. i have to write a variable so that we can pass any number of module names with out changing

Comment: @somesh What output do you *want* from doing that? This is a very specific question, we're not asking what do you think you're doing.

Comment: @blckknght mod.%str(10, 20, 30, 40) this is a sample example i have written in sample.py and i have to call Login_CSA module where i have given str="Login_CSA" in this "str" from our frame work there will the many modules coming..so i have to pass dynamically that is my requirement can u please help me

Comment: @alKid i want to call Login_CSA module from sample.py module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to do this. Instead of

```
mod.%str(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

use

```
getattr(mod, str)(10, 20, 30, 40)
```